# getting error :Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'. while add column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

When I run query into SQL Server, it gives me error

> Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'

Can anyone please tell me where did I make a mistake? Here is my SQL query for this:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_sticky_data ADD regions_id VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL DEFAULT(0) AFTER branch_id;
```

Thanks for taking your time, I know this is very simple but I am new in SQL so I am getting trouble in it.

Comment: you have mis-tagged. AFTER is MySQL not SQL Server

Comment: AFTER is not SQL and the order does not matter in SQL, just change your insert, update, select statements will change the order

Comment: Why do you care about column order anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AFTER` is MySQL-syntax.

In SQL Server that does not work. You need to recreate the table.

Only possibility is to move the column in design-mode by using SQL Server Management Studio. But in fact this will recreate the table too.

Comment: Or not - why would column order matter?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, column order allows one wants to physically group logically related columns (e.g. address columns). Otherwise, order doesn't matter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The only reason I can see is aesthetics. Maybe the order of  `SELECT * ...` is of importance for OP...

Comment: @DanGuzman no it doesn't. There's no grouping involved. In fact, such a "requirement" is a smell that suggests normalization is violated and the fields should be extacted to their own table. If you treat some fields as if they were value objects, you care about their *names*, not their order anyway.

Comment: @DanGuzman order matters in *indexes*, especially clustered indexes.

Comment: pretty sure Dan knows that! :)

Comment: All too well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to insert a new column directly adjascent to the existing branch_Id column.

Take the AFTER sytax out of the query.

So just

```
ALTER TABLE tb_sticky_data ADD regions_id VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL DEFAULT(0)
```

Then if you want to shuffle the column order, right click on the table and choose DESIGN. From this view you can re-order any columns in the table.

Comment: @TirkeshTurkesh Note that when you change the order of columns via SSMS, it will drop/recreate the table. The only way to use ALTER TABLE to add columns is to be willing to accept that they go in the last ordinal positions. The reason for this is that the ALTER TABLE does not actually add the column to the existing rows. It simply changes metadata.